# Pass nested json item name to function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I have nested json data with objects Account and Category.Category is in account json data.I pass default columns to map function and it creates my columns.But if i pass Category.Name i cant see on screen.How can i pass nested data property name to this function ?

```
//Default Columns:
this.defaultColumns = ["Name","Limit","Category.Name"];      

//My Function:
that.props.results.map(function(rowData){
            return (
                <tr>
                {that.props.defaultColumns.map(function (column) {
                   return (
                        <td>{rowData[column]}</td>
                    );
                </tr>})}
```

JSON Data:

```
[{
    "RowNumber":"e0275f18-f86a-1d2e-97e6-b8ce9a4a7fef",
    "Name":1,
    "Limit":78,
    "Category":{
      "RowNumber":"b72a77db-8c44-8b59-5044-3c42595203aa",
      "Name":"Produce"
    }
}]
```

Comment: A sample of your JSON would be clearer than describing it.

Comment: `<tr>` is not valid syntax in JavaScript, unless that's React's .jsx . Do you mean to be returning a string?

Comment: sorry copy paste problem.In my screen i can see Name - Limit columns but cant see Category.Name column

Comment: Well, you don't have a property with name `Category.Name`, only with name `Category`. Did you expect `rowData['Category.Name']` to magically access the nested property?

Comment: but i have Name in category i want show this date.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you know that or not, but you cannot access a nested property via `rowData['Category.Name']`. This would *literally* try to access the property with name `Category.Name`, i.e. it would work if you had an object like

```
{
    'Cateogry.Name': 42
}
```

One thing you can do is specify render functions for each of your columns. The those render functions define how to access the data for each of the columns. For example:

```
var columnRenderer = {
  Name: x => x,
  Limit: x => x,
  Category: x => x.Name
};
```

Then, given your columns as

```
//Default Columns:
this.defaultColumns = ["Name","Limit","Category"];
```

You can render the table with

```
that.props.results.map(
  rowData =>
    <tr>
      {that.props.defaultColumns.map(
        column => <td>{columnRenderer(rowData[column])}</td>
      )}
    </tr>
);
```

(Note: I am using arrow functions here, an ES6 feature, so if you are using the jsx command line tools, you have to pass the `--harmony` option, or use normal functions instead).

Comment: i use this in grid.And its in lot of pages.How can i write this generic version ?

Comment: Are you saying you have other data and don't want write a renderer for every column? Or what exactly do you find too specific about this solution?

Comment: yes i dont want write renderer for every column. ["Name","Limit","Category"]; i want pass the column names like this and method will handle this.